# Why the server boots up multiple sidekiq processes? How to put them down?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, puma

I deployed a rails app with puma(3.4.0) and sidekiq(3.0.2). Almost all of the configrations are default value by capistrano-puma and capistrano-sidekiq. But I don't know why multiple sidekiq processes turned up and occupy the memory.

Screenshot of htop: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ibien.png)

Sidekiq has concurrency feature so that i only want one sidekiq process. Any help with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things:

1. htop shows all threads as different PIDs by default.  Press "Shift-H" to see only processes or use `top` to see only processes.
2. capistrano-sidekiq can start up N processes, you need to configure it to start 1.
3. 3.0.2 is ancient.  Upgrade, man.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I also thought the reason is that capistrano-sidekiq started up multiple processes. But as [link](https://github.com/seuros/capistrano-sidekiq#usage) mentioned, the default config is 1 process. Besides i set the process to 1 again and it doesn't work. Do you know how to config this? I'll upgrade the sidekiq and try again. Thank you!

Comment: Upgraded sidekiq has the same problem. I wonder if it was caused by puma?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to reply. Actually, Mike is right. The reason that I saw multiple sidekiqs on my htop is just because htop shows threads instead of processes. Thx a lot.